# How to open ActionCall Activity from DependencyServic in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Hi I am facing a very simple problem but I am not exactly sure why?

I am trying to call directly from xamarin forms app, without showing dailer screen, user will see list of its contacts in a screen click a button to call, and it will make a direct call without showing dialer screen.

to achieve this I have used DependencyServic and I have used this as my base https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e4bad6/code-to-start-call-in-xamarin-forms/

the only difference is this is PCL and I am using shared library

Where I am getting Problem?

**My Interface**

```
public interface IPhoneCall
    {
        void MakeQuickCall(string PhoneNumber);
    }
```

**My call to Dependency Service**

```
private void makeCall_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                DependencyService.Get<IPhoneCall>().MakeQuickCall("+xxxxxxxxx");
            } catch(Exception ex)
            {
                DisplayAlert("Alert!!!", ex.Message, "ok");
            }
        }
```

**My Dependency service call for Android:**

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(PhoneCall_Droid))]
namespace MakeCall.Droid
{
    public class PhoneCall_Droid : IPhoneCall
    {
        public void MakeQuickCall(string PhoneNumber)
        {
            try
            {
                var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(string.Format("tel:{0}", PhoneNumber));
                var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionCall, uri);
                Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.StartActivity(intent);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(Android.App.Application.Context).SetPositiveButton("OK", (sender, args) =>
                {
                    //User pressed OK
                })
                .SetMessage(ex.ToString())
                .SetTitle("Android Exception")
                .Show();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This alert is returning an exception ***Unable to add window - token null is not valid; is your activity running?***

I have looked different solutions like this

[Intent ActionCall is not making phone call in xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51571996/intent-actioncall-is-not-making-phone-call-in-xamarin-forms)

and this
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/129166/unable-to-add-window-token-null-is-not-for-an-application-alertbuilder

but I am still not able to sort this, out,

also I tried this in my **Main activity**

```
internal static MainActivity Instance { get; private set; }
```

and then added this line in **OnCreate** method

```
Instance = this;
```

and changed my Android dependency service class method to this

```
public void MakeQuickCall(string PhoneNumber)
        {
            var context = MainActivity.Instance;
            try
            {

                new AlertDialog.Builder(context ).SetPositiveButton("OK", (sender, args) =>
                {
                    //User pressed OK
                })
                .SetMessage(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(string.Format("tel:{0}", PhoneNumber)).ToString())
                .SetTitle("Android Exception")
                .Show();



                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionCall, Android.Net.Uri.Parse(string.Format("tel:{0}", PhoneNumber)));
                context.StartActivity(intent);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(Android.App.Application.Context).SetPositiveButton("OK", (sender, args) =>
                {
                    //User pressed OK
                })
                .SetMessage(ex.ToString())
                .SetTitle("Android Exception")
                .Show();
            }
        }
```

and by doing this alert is showing the dailed phone number, but it is not calling and for call part is still showing same of **unable to add window ..,**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue at my side, if you request the [runtime permissions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/) after Android 6.0, you will solved your issue.

Firstly, you could defined a static variable in MainActiviy:

```
 public static MainActivity macvivity;
   
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
      
        macvivity = this;    
   
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);          
        LoadApplication(new App());
     

    }
```

Then requesting permissions before call:

```
 public void MakeQuickCall(string PhoneNumber)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(MainActivity.macvivity, Android.Manifest.Permission.CallPhone) != Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted)
            {

                ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(MainActivity.macvivity, new string[] { Android.Manifest.Permission.CallPhone }, 1);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(string.Format("tel:{0}", PhoneNumber));
                var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionCall, uri);
                Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.StartActivity(intent);
                //MainActivity.macvivity.StartActivity(intent);
            }               
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(Android.App.Application.Context).SetPositiveButton("OK", (sender, args) =>
            {
                //User pressed OK
            })
            .SetMessage(ex.ToString())
            .SetTitle("Android Exception")
            .Show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Thanks I will try it

Comment: @Creative, Anything update? My reply solved your issue now?

Comment: I am still getting same error not sure why? should I create a demo app with single screen and send it to you to have a look

Comment: it is going to permission section of the condition you created, does this show that there is some permission required but but it is not asking for any permission just doing nothing there

Comment: @Creative, I suggest you add some code about requesting permission, I have the same issue if I don't add the request permission, and it works fine when I adding requesting code.